# How can i install npm in ubuntu to run less js

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, compilation, less, npm

I have already installed node js in my ubuntu 14.04, but I am not able to install `npm` in it.  I want to compile `less` through command line so that I need `npm`.

Is there any way to compile `less` or how can i install `npm` in ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first, run `sudo apt-get update`.

npm should be installed along with node.js. It's possible that you have a name collision issue; the Ubuntu repository carries a program called 'Node' (a program for HAM radio operators) which is unrelated to node.js. Further, many node modules assume that 'node' refers to node.js.

Try removing Node:

`sudo apt-get remove node`

Use `which nodejs` to see where the command for node.js lives. Create a symlink somewhere in your path so that `node` points to `nodejs`, e.g.

`sudo ln -s [path/to/nodejs/here] /usr/bin/node`

After that, `/usr/bin` should be in your system's PATH variable, so you should just be able to use node.js by typing 'node'. E.g. try `node --version`. It should match `nodejs --version`.

If none of that works, you can also try removing nodejs and node, then install nodejs-legacy, which is supposed to use the command 'node' by default. Also consider installing node.js from another source. You can find binary and source downloads at nodejs.org, or you can get the latest version from GitHub (joyent/node).

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply:

```
sudo apt-get install npm
```

Comment: when i run this command and then it shows " Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
"

Comment: That problem is not related to installing `npm` (which can be done through `apt-get`, to solve that error check [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)